# libcurl compile error in 64bit Centos when passing -m32 parameter

Tags: libcurl, centos6

Please help!

I'm having the problem below when compiling my code. Do you have any fix on the libcurl issue esp the missing file? I am using Centos 64bit. m32 option is needed because some shared object is 32bit.

---

```
g++ -c -g -m32 -o c-wrapper.o c-wrapper.cpp -D__C_FILES "-I../include" -DLINUX
gcc -c -g -m32 -o Example_c.o `mysql_config --libs` -lcurl  Example_c.c -D__C_FILES "-    I../include" -DLINUX
In file included from /usr/include/curl/curl.h:43,
             from Example_c.c:2:
/usr/include/curl/curlbuild.h:4:26: error: curlbuild-32.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/curl/curl.h:44,
             from Example_c.c:2:
/usr/include/curl/curlrules.h:80:4: error: #error "CURL_SIZEOF_LONG definition is missing!"
In file included from /usr/include/curl/curl.h:44,
```

...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo yum install libcurl-devel.i686
```